# How to join elements of two different objects in python

Tags: python, json

I have following data in JSON. The purpose is to give my program commands given below, and the city names and it searches the weather information about that particular city. (I have not included the code that searches the weather data)

```
{"tag": "weather",
         "patterns": ["how will be weather today in" ,"What is the weather like in", "what is the weather in"],

         "responses": [""]

        }
```

And my python script

```
            if i['tag'] == 'weather':
               cities = [' karachi', ' lahore', ' islamabad', ' rawalpindi']
               for pattern in i['patterns']:
                    pattern+=cities
                   print(pattern)
```

It prints the following statements

```
how will be weather today in[' karachi', ' lahore', ' islamabad', ' rawalpindi']
What is the weather like in[' karachi', ' lahore', ' islamabad', ' rawalpindi']
what is the weather in[' karachi', ' lahore', ' islamabad', ' rawalpindi']
```

What I want it to print

```
What is the weather like in karachi
What is the weather like in islamabad
what is the weather like in rawalpindi
```

and so on. I also tried to use **pattern+=cities[0]** and it prints

*What is the weather like in karachi* only and ignores all other cities. I'm new to python and may not have explained everything correctly. Hope someone could help me out.

Comment: why do you want 'lahore' to be skipped in the output?

Comment: It was just to refer that I want only one city at a time. Of course lahore will be included

Comment: Then perhaps you should correct the sample output.

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops:

```
for pattern in i['patterns']:
    for city in cities:
        print(pattern + city)
```

Comment: One more question if you don't mind.

Is it possible to print the statement with only that city which is mentioned in the question rather than printing all of them? 

For example I type in question: "How is weather in Karachi" and it prints only for karachi

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed sure, just store the input and don't use a loop. In this case it sounds like the input and the output are the same so I don't understand what you're trying to do anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Will go through it.